# Primefaces lazy Datatable with no total rows count

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a PrimeFaces DataTable where I have pagination (the component one, no custom) in form of two arrows (back and forward).

The table never knows how many rows are there, so I have the following function to set the rows count (keep in mind that the `dataSize` parameter is for a `pageSize` of 25 rows always 25 or less):

```
if(pageNumber == 0 && dataSize < pageSize) {
    setRowCount(dataSize);
} else if(pageNumber != 0 && dataSize < pageSize) {
    setRowCount(pageNumber*pageSize + dataSize);
} else {
    setRowCount(pageSize*(pageNumber+1) + 1);
}
```

With this function called in the load method after fetching the data, there are always one page or two pages or three pages. Depending on the current position of the first record the back arrow or the forward arrow are disabled or enabled. This all works well so far.

Now I want to be able to load the table on a given page. If I have a `pageNumber` the correct set of data is displayed but only the forward arrow is enabled. So the DataTable thinks that it is on the first page. I tried to call the `setRowIndex()` before or after my function but no luck.

Does anybody know how to make DataTable think that there is also a page before the current one?

Comment: Which datamodel are you using?

Comment: I've overriden the LazyDataModel.